# How to Read and Write files from Azure Web App to an on premise NAS?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, network-storage

I have a web app (.NET MVC) running on an Azure App Service. This application creates some PDF files and i want to store them in an on-premise NAS in my organization that requires credentials to access it.

1. How is this possible?
2. Is it secure?
3. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. To realize it as the figure below shown, the two requirements are as below.

[image]

1. There is an on-premise server can mount your on-premise NAS Filesystem for reading and writing files.
2. On Azure, you need to create a VPN gateway to build a Site-to-Site VPN connection for helping your Azure WebApp to request your on-premise server to relay the file operations.

For more details about Azure VPN Gateway, please refer to the offical tutorial [`Create a Site-to-Site connection in the Azure portal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal) to know how to get started.

And yes, it's secure. I think it's a general solution.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I thought that App service blocks required ports. Is this not correct? Did you manage to implement it @mike_x_?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/290531/how-can-i-access-a-on-premise-network-file-share-d.html
"And the App Service sandbox explicitly does not allow access to the ports necessary for SMB protocol (137/138/139/445)."