# Save file from App Service to on-premise network share

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a requirement to create and save file from web application hosted in Azure App Service (ASE, Linux) to Network share on-premise. Network share already exists and is being written to by applications which I don't have control over. App Service is blocking ports so I can't write to network share directly. Assuming Azure to On premise connection is configured correctly what options do I have?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into [git hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/290531/how-can-i-access-a-on-premise-network-file-share-d.html) issue

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT What if I'm using Linux container?

Comment: Refer [Mount SMB Azure file share on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux?tabs=smb311)

Comment: You could also use the FTP if your needs are met

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how Azure file share of FTP would help me here. As mentioned this network share already exists. In addition few apps already write to it and can't be modified. Then there is another app that monitors this network share for new files.

Comment: Please refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56952303/how-to-read-and-write-files-from-azure-web-app-to-an-on-premise-nas).Looks like the same

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT interesting. But this is from issue you gave link to - "And the App Service sandbox explicitly does not allow access to the ports necessary for SMB protocol (137/138/139/445)."